# Downvoting an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

I answered this question over at SE a few months back:

[How to creating MS Access database without MS Access application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524367/how-to-creating-ms-access-database-without-ms-access-application/17526809#17526809)

So someone comes along and edits it (How deleting a single tag is not considered "Too minor" when there are obvious gramatical errors all over the post is beyond me...) which puts the question back on Page 1.  Someone comes along and downvotes my answer, after it was accepted and it's definitely correct.

Once an answer is accepted, shouldn't it be locked to prevent this?  If it's accepted, it was presumably helpful to the OP and I think it should be immune to downvotes.  Someone else can certainly come along and add their comments if they feel they have another answer, or add a comment to the accepted answer explaining why it may not be relevant or whatever a downvote on SE is supposed to signify.

Comment: Accepted means "worked for me" by the OP. Doesn't mean "this is correct".

Comment: Sometimes the accepted answer is wrong (not saying yours is) so downvotes can't be locked

Comment: So every single person that asks a question is infallible; they can never possibly accept an answer that doesn't work, or that is a poor answer despite helping them?  You're going to need to prove that if you feel that they shouldn't be voted on.

Comment: What does the edit have to do with this?  the fact that you bring it up makes it sound like the tag edit somehow changed the question so your answer was not correct

Comment: Instead of answering the question, shouldn't you be flagging it for moderator attention (since you can't vote to close yet) since it's asking for tool recommendations?

Comment: Since you have asserted that an answer that is accepted is obviously perfect and could never possibly be wrong, of poor quality, or unhelpful, in addition to locking downvotes we should also lock upvotes.  I mean, we already know that it's the perfect answer, there's no real compelling reason to have other people indicating that they find it useful since we already *know* that it's perfect.

Comment: Someone with 2K+ rep is free to edit posts without review; changing tags is just fine.

Comment: @Servy - I totally agree.

Comment: It's not unheard of for some people to make a minor edit to a post so that they can revoke an upvote or downvote - not sure why, maybe it gives them another vote if they reached the daily cap. Perhaps that's a possible explanation?

Comment: @RogerRowland Nope; Will just likes cleaning up tags a lot, so he frequently goes around untagging the evil tag of the day from all questions using it.

Comment: @Servy oh, okay, just thinking out loud ....

Comment: It is however a little cruel to heavily down vote an accepted answer as they cannot be deleted by their author

Comment: @RichardTingle - Doesn't bother me.  I like to be downvoted once in a while.  It's the SO equivalent of S&M.  :oP

Comment: @RichardTingle disagree with downvoting an accepted answer in general, but downvoting a specific answer that you found from a meta post is a little unfair unless there is a very specific reason for it.  However, it is a risk you run when you bring your own post up on meta.

Comment: The whole situation here seems really bizarre, the OP comments saying "this isn't what I want", then accepts the answer locking it in place. Really really strange

Comment: @RichardTingle I consider downvotes on an unhelpful accepted answer to be much, much more important than any other downvotes you can cast.  That the answer is accepted means that many people are going to be under the impression that it's a good answer.  If it's not, it is *very* important that readers be given as much indication as is possible that the answer should not be used, and that another answer should be used instead.  Even if the author can't delete it, they can still edit it into a helpful answer.

Comment: @Servy By heavily downvoted I mean; once it hits -3. Obviously downvotes are needed until its clearly marked as unhelpful. Of course the answerer may realise they are out of their depth and are not able to edit it to be correct. Say I (idiotically) answered a javascript question with a java answer which was then accepted by an over eager OP

Comment: Well, Servy, my answer is actually correct. There may be other tools, but technically it's 100% correct. So, the downvotes are kind of a joke to me and a disservice to this site.

Comment: given that asker is free to unaccept the answer any time they want, this would put voting into a senseless dependency of the asker's state of mind (while it is supposed to be based on post content)

Comment: @JohnnyBones I never used the word "correct" or "incorrect" in my comment.  I used the word "unhelpful".  Just because an answer is correct doesn't mean it's useful/helpful.

Comment: Well that's a first.  So correct answers aren't helpful?  Well, now I'll just put a bunch of incorrect answers out there!

Comment: @RichardTingle True, although the cases where such an answer gets accepted are rare.  One could flag for mod attention; they might consider deleting the answer.  At the very least, you could disassociate it from your account.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I never said all correct answers aren't helpful, I said not all correct answers are helpful.  A correct answer *can* be unhelpful or it can be helpful.

Comment: @JohnnyBones we are talking about downvotes on accepted answer **in general**, not regarding your answer in particular

Comment: As my go to example for an unhelpful correct answer "Java is pass by value, not pass by reference", true but deeply misleading because it passes a reference by value

Comment: I always saw downvotes as a way to help the asker, who obviously doesn't know the answer or they wouldn't be asking the question, determine which answer might be most helpful.  Then the asker can use that "suggestion" to try a solution.  If the solution works, the OP is satisfied, gives the checkmark, and everyone has a beer.  Going back and basically saying, "OP, you're a dunce.  This isn't the best answer but I'm not going to tell you a better one" is non-constructive.  Yet allowed.

Comment: @JohnnyBones votes (down or up doesn't matter) are first of all to help the readers of the post, all the readers, not just (and not even primarily to) asker

Comment: @JohnnyBones 1) That assumes that questions exist solely to help the OP.  That is false.  They exist to help the internet as a whole through the creation of a repository of knowledge.  The author is just one of many people that should be helped. 2) Telling the OP that the answer that they think is a good solution is in fact a bad solution is *very important*.  They may not have the expertise to understand why it's a bad solution, why it may work for the example given but not other cases, or why it introduced other significant negative side effects.  Informing them of that is *valuable*.

Comment: Then I've been voting (and answering, for that matter) wrong this entire time...

Comment: @JohnnyBones 3) Who says that there is never an alternative given?  There may well be another answer that has a positive score that's much better.  And regardless, knowing that a given solution is bad and shouldn't be used is still valuable information.  Better to know that you don't know the answer than to think that you know the answer when you're wrong.  The latter is *much, much worse* than the former.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Perhaps, but the two probably ended up in the same place (apart from ignoring everything after the checkmark)

Comment: @JohnnyBones Apparently so.  Now you know.  That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 25):

No, accepted answers should not be immune to downvotes.

There are incorrect accepted answers out there, and downvotes are the only means we have to reduce the visibility of those answers relative to correct but unaccepted ones.

Comment: Why would someone accept an incorrect answer?  Maybe the person who accepts an incorrect answer should get the ding on their rep for accepting the wrong answer?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Possibly because they don't know better.  It's not like all questions asked on this site are asked by experts in their field that never make mistakes (and, for that matter, even experts make occasional mistakes).

Comment: [Evidence](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A-100..-5+isaccepted%3Ayes), horrible horrible evidence

Comment: @RichardTingle a [better search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A..-1) for even better evidence

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=70904&tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3ayes

Comment: @JohnnyBones- Possibly the [latest case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202998/216721).

Answer (score 7):

People can downvote for whatever reason they like. Same with upvotes. Maybe they think your answer isn't detailed enough. Maybe they don't like Access. Maybe they don't like your avatar. Maybe they're having a bad day.

You can't compel them to tell you *why* if they don't feel like it.

As for possibly making accepted answers immune from downvotes, that's a bad idea. The OP is often the last person to see what is a good solution to their problem. They, however, are the only ones who can say if a specific answer solved the problem for them.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, that was me.

[I'm burning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202684/burninate-tools) the [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) tag.

I gots the rep, so I can remove a tag without having my edit go through the approval process.  Now, I didn't edit the question because it is a turd and I don't polish them, I just cut them.  I VTC that bastard (as you will note I'm the first on the close list) and left it for the flies.

I can only spare a bit of free time every day to this kind of thing, and editing crap questions that need to get deleted **is not on that list**.

Shopping questions are awful and should be punishable by horsewhipping.  I can't horsewhip through the intertubes, but I can sure as hell downvote people who ask them and those that help these defilers in their act.

Comment: Alas, the roomba doesn't delete questions with accepted answers.